# R programming - data frame manoevur

Tags: r, data-structures, dataset

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   dc tmin tmax cint wcmin wcmax wsmin wsmax gsmin gsmax  wd rmin rmax  cir lr
1: 24   -1    4    5    -5    -2    20    25    35    40  90 11.8 26.6 14.8  3
2: 41   -3    5    8    -8    -3    15    20    35    40  90 10.0 23.5 13.5  3
3: 48    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
4: 50    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
5: 52    3    5    2    -3     1    20    25    35    40  45  6.7 17.4 10.7  6
6: 57   -2    5    7    -6    -1    25    30    35    40 315  4.4 13.8  9.4  7
   lc wc    li yd   yr nF factdcx
1:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  2      24
2:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  8      41
3:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      48
4:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      50
5:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      52
6:  3  3 FALSE  1 2010  0      57
```

I'd like to turn it into a new dataframe like the following:

```
   dc tmin tmax cint wcmin wcmax wsmin wsmax gsmin gsmax  wd rmin rmax  cir lr
1: 24   -1    4    5    -5    -2    20    25    35    40  90 11.8 26.6 14.8  3
2: 41   -3    5    8    -8    -3    15    20    35    40  90 10.0 23.5 13.5  3
3: 48    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
4: 52    3    5    2    -3     1    20    25    35    40  45  6.7 17.4 10.7  6
5: 57   -2    5    7    -6    -1    25    30    35    40 315  4.4 13.8  9.4  7
   lc wc    li yd   yr nF                                       factdcx
1:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  2                                        24  
2:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  8                                        41
3:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0 (sum of nF for 48 and 50, factdcx)     48
4:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0                                        52 
5:  3  3 FALSE  1 2010  0                                        57
```

How can I do it? (Surely, the dataframe, abc, is much larger, but I want the sum of all categories of 48 and 50 and group it into a new category, say '48').

Many thanks!

```
> dput(head(abc1))
structure(list(dc = c(24L, 41L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 57L), tmin = c(-1L, 
-3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, -2L), tmax = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), cint = c(5L,
8L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L), wcmin = c(-5L, -8L, -4L, -4L, -3L, -6L), 
wcmax = c(-2L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L), wsmin = c(20L, 15L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 25L), wsmax = c(25L, 20L, 35L, 35L, 25L, 30L
), gsmin = c(35L, 35L, 45L, 45L, 35L, 35L), gsmax = c(40L, 
40L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 40L), wd = c(90L, 90L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
315L), rmin = c(11.8, 10, 7.3, 7.3, 6.7, 4.4), rmax = c(26.6, 
23.5, 19, 19, 17.4, 13.8), cir = c(14.8, 13.5, 11.7, 11.7, 
10.7, 9.4), lr = c(3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), lc = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), wc = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), li = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), yd = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), yr = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), nF = c(2L, 
8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), factdcx = structure(1:6, .Label = c("24", 
"41", "48", "50", "52", "57", "70"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dc", 
"tmin", "tmax", "cint", "wcmin", "wcmax", "wsmin", "wsmax", "gsmin", 
"gsmax", "wd", "rmin", "rmax", "cir", "lr", "lc", "wc", "li", 
"yd", "yr", "nF", "factdcx"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x054b24a0>)
```

Still got a problem, sir/madam:

```
 > head(abc1 (updated))
   dc tmin tmax cint wcmin wcmax wsmin wsmax gsmin gsmax  wd rmin rmax  cir lr
1: 24   -1    4    5    -5    -2    20    25    35    40  90 11.8 26.6 14.8  3
2: 41   -3    5    8    -8    -3    15    20    35    40  90 10.0 23.5 13.5  3
3: 48    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
4: 52    3    5    2    -3     1    20    25    35    40  45  6.7 17.4 10.7  6
5: 57   -2    5    7    -6    -1    25    30    35    40 315  4.4 13.8  9.4  7
6: 70   -2    3    5    -4    -1    20    25    30    35 360  3.6 10.2  6.6  7
   lc wc    li yd   yr nF factdcx
1:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  2      24
2:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  8      41
3:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010 57      48
4:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      52
5:  3  3 FALSE  1 2010  0      57
6:  3  2  TRUE  1 2010  1      70
```

The sum of nF was incorrect, it should be zero.

Comment: I am not getting that kind of an output if you check my post. If you have run the code a couple of times, it may happen.  Try it again on your original dataset.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same output as above, I think this has to do with the sum(nF) code.

Comment: I am using the same dataset that you posted with the dput.  Based on that dataset ie. `abc1 <- structure(..`, I get `0` for `nF` where you showed `57`

Comment: The problem I guess is that the dataset I posed is only the head() of it. The full dataset is much longer. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, my output was based on the `head(abc1)`.  I think you run the code on the full dataset, so it should be different.

Comment: I guess some sort of function is required here but this is far beyond my ability. What should I do then? '><

Comment: As I said earlier, based on your initial info and the dataset showed, I got the expected output.   But, the new info that 48, and 50 should be next to each other is completely different case.   I already spend a lot of time on this and I anticipate that you will come up with a new condition if I try with the next to each other condition.

Comment: I am so sorry about this. Thanks for your time anyway. It is indeed a very tricky question.

Comment: I can test on it but please don't come up with a new condition.

Comment: Can you test `unique(abc1[, factdcx:= as.character(factdcx)][factdcx==50 & shift(factdcx)[[1L]]==48|factdcx==48 & shift(factdcx, type='lead')[[1L]]==50, c('dc', 'factdcx', 'nF'):= list(48, '48', sum(nF))])` assuming that you have the devel version of `data.table`.  Installation instructions are here
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: But the full dataset is too long, the dput() output exceed the length of the output space available. Moreover, I can't reveal the entire dataset publicly. The thing I'd like to do is basically to sum the neighboring the nF of 48 and 50 factdcx output, it is characterized by yd. For each yd value, from 1-365, these eight districts recur once. So for each day 1, 2, ..., 365 I'd like to sum the each pair of nFs for factdcx 48 and 50 but return only the 48 line.

Comment: Based on the new info, you may have some grouping variables.  In that case, use `by=list(your grouping variables)]` in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1)[, factdcx:= as.character(factdcx)][factdcx %chin% 
  c('48','50'), c('dc', 'factdcx', 'nF') := list('48', '48', sum(nF))])
#    dc tmin tmax cint wcmin wcmax wsmin wsmax gsmin gsmax  wd rmin rmax  cir lr
#1: 24   -1    4    5    -5    -2    20    25    35    40  90 11.8 26.6 14.8  3
#2: 41   -3    5    8    -8    -3    15    20    35    40  90 10.0 23.5 13.5  3
#3: 48    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
#4: 52    3    5    2    -3     1    20    25    35    40  45  6.7 17.4 10.7  6
#5: 57   -2    5    7    -6    -1    25    30    35    40 315  4.4 13.8  9.4  7
#   lc wc    li yd   yr nF factdcx
#1:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  2      24
#2:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  8      41
#3:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      48
#4:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      52
#5:  3  3 FALSE  1 2010  0      57
```

For `abc1`,

```
 res1 <- unique(setDT(abc1)[, factdcx:= as.character(factdcx)][factdcx %chin% 
   c('48','50'), c('dc', 'factdcx', 'nF') := list(48, '48', sum(nF))])
 res1
#     dc tmin tmax cint wcmin wcmax wsmin wsmax gsmin gsmax  wd rmin rmax  cir lr
#1: 24   -1    4    5    -5    -2    20    25    35    40  90 11.8 26.6 14.8  3
#2: 41   -3    5    8    -8    -3    15    20    35    40  90 10.0 23.5 13.5  3
#3: 48    0    5    5    -4     0    30    35    45    50  45  7.3 19.0 11.7  6
#4: 52    3    5    2    -3     1    20    25    35    40  45  6.7 17.4 10.7  6
#5: 57   -2    5    7    -6    -1    25    30    35    40 315  4.4 13.8  9.4  7
#   lc wc    li yd   yr nF factdcx
#1:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  2      24
#2:  1  3  TRUE  1 2010  8      41
#3:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      48
#4:  2  3  TRUE  1 2010  0      52
#5:  3  3 FALSE  1 2010  0      57
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(dc = structure(1:6, .Label = c("24", "41",
"48", 
"50", "52", "57"), class = "factor"), tmin = c(-1L, -3L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, -2L), tmax = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), cint = c(5L, 
8L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L), wcmin = c(-5L, -8L, -4L, -4L, -3L, -6L), 
wcmax = c(-2L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L), wsmin = c(20L, 15L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 25L), wsmax = c(25L, 20L, 35L, 35L, 25L, 30L
), gsmin = c(35L, 35L, 45L, 45L, 35L, 35L), gsmax = c(40L, 
40L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 40L), wd = c(90L, 90L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
315L), rmin = c(11.8, 10, 7.3, 7.3, 6.7, 4.4), rmax = c(26.6, 
23.5, 19, 19, 17.4, 13.8), cir = c(14.8, 13.5, 11.7, 11.7, 
10.7, 9.4), lr = c(3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), lc = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), wc = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), li = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), yd = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), yr = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), nF = c(2L, 
8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), factdcx = structure(1:6, .Label = c("24", 
"41", "48", "50", "52", "57"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dc", 
"tmin", "tmax", "cint", "wcmin", "wcmax", "wsmin", "wsmax", "gsmin", 
 "gsmax", "wd", "rmin", "rmax", "cir", "lr", "lc", "wc", "li", 
"yd", "yr", "nF", "factdcx"), row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", 
"4:", "5:", "6:"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. But what if the nominal variable takes an integer form, say a=14, b=28, c=33, etc. ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I got some errors, they go:

Comment: In '[.data.table'(set......
Supplied 21 columns to be assigned a list (length 2) of values (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).

Comment: Thanks again. I still got warning messages:
1. In '[.data.table'(setDT(df1),var1%in%c("48","50"),':='(names(df1)[21:22],:
Coerced 'character' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'character' first or coerce RHS to'integer' to make your intent clear.

2.RHS contains 994 which is outside the levels range([1,7]) of column 2, NAs generated.

Comment: Before I try again, I just want to confirm something. I have got 20 columns in the dataset, besides the numeric variable which I would like to sum, the other columns of the 2 categories, 48 and 50, are equal. Will the above be useful in this case.

Comment: Basically I'll edit the question again just to be sure.

Comment: Sorry to be so annoying, but I've updated once and for all the data set. Would you have a look please? This is the actual dataset. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly! But there are other columns after factdcx which I have omitted. Cheers!

Comment: That was the un-factored column. I'd like to keep the original column as well.

Comment: There is still a problem, I have updated the answer show the R output.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the str(abc) consists of class data.table and data.frame while str(df4) only consists of data.frame.

Comment: What do you mean by dput output? I am quite new to this page, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @mackbox Can you test the updated code?  In my previous code, I thought `dc` was also factor class.  As it is 'integer' class, we can use `48` instead of `"48"`.

Comment: I think the problem is that factdcx is recurring(24, 41, 48, 50, 52, 57, 70 then comes 24, 41,... again until the last observation). I have over 2000 observations, and I only want the sum of nF of the neighboring two factdcx (48 and 50, in each cycle).

Comment: You deserve more upvotes for the hard work you've put here :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the motivation.  I just noticed that a similar question posted by the OP got your answer.

Comment: Yes. He cross-posted on CV. But your initial answer was much better than mine. I will close it a s a dupe of this as it seems like this is more up to date.